# Graphics problem in ubuntu 14.04. Everything looking like windows 98 and terminal is totally black

Tags: 14.04, graphics

[This is the image showing how my ubuntu looks now:

[image]

Please help me reset it back to normal

Comment: And what did you do to get Ubuntu to look the way it does?

Comment: I don't know which command did it. but i want to reset it to the original. Please help me fix.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on Desktop -> Change Desktop Background -> 
 in the Theme select Radiance or Ambiance(default), Even if some of them already selected.

If it's not solved, you probably changed your theme via unity-tweak-tool or Ubuntu-Tweak or something else, you can change your theme to normal in there.